# Set html audio play/pause based on a cookie (works only on pause, but not on play)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to make background audio remember the play/pause state. I have achieved pausing it and storing the pause state in the cookie, so when I go between page one and two it stays paused (vs autoplaying initially on both pages), but when I click play after that and refresh the page, even though the cookie is changing to "false" in the inspector, the audio doesn't play and the div colour doesn't change to green.

Live demo https://timcliss.webflow.io/audio-test

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dmitry-ra/pen/zYqMozV)

Here is the code

**External Scripts**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2.2.1/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="div" id="toggle"> PLAY/PAUSE </div>
<audio id="player" src="https://storage.yandexcloud.net/timcliss/About.mp3" autoplay loop>
```

**CSS**

```
.div {
background-color:green;
height: 50px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
```

**JS**

```
var audio = $('#player')[0];
audio.volume = 0.5;

var isMuted = Cookies.get('playerMuted'); // Receive stored cookie
if(isMuted) // If muted, stop the player
{
$('#player')[0].pause();
$('#toggle').css({'background-color': 'red'});
} 
else
{
$('#player')[0].play();
$('#toggle').css({'background-color': 'green'});
}

// This function will be called when you click the toggle div
function toggleMute() 
{
if(isMuted) // If player is muted, then unmute it
{
$('#player')[0].play();
$('#toggle').css({'background-color': 'green'});
isMuted = false;
} else // Else mute it
{
$('#player')[0].pause();
$('#toggle').css({'background-color': 'red'});
isMuted = true;
}
Cookies.set('playerMuted', isMuted); // Save current state of player
}

$('#toggle').click(toggleMute);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, turns out I just needed to use

```
if(isMuted=='true')
```

and then `isMuted = 'false'; or isMuted = 'true';`

Here is the [updated pen](https://codepen.io/dmitry-ra/pen/zYqMozV)

Works like a clock in Chrome with autoplay enabled! :)

Safari is more strict with the autoplay, so I added a check and only run this code for Chrome, and run standard player for Safari

```
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if(isSafari){ 
alert('Is safari');
//Do something

} else {
alert('Is other browser');
// Do something
}
```

If someone finds a workaround for autoplay in Safari, or if you need help with implementing it in Chrome please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In new browsers audio autoplay is not supported and user has to explicitly play audio that is why play part is not working. You can read more about it here
(https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not correct. It already plays automatically from the start in Chrome without user interaction, so I don't see why it wouldn't after setting the cookie. Apart from that the div color doesn't change either, so it seems like there is an issue with the if / else , but I can't figure it out.

Comment: are you sure your code reaches the else part.(try putting a console.log statement in it) also i am sure you might have given a look to this but the background color of your div is already green try changing it to some other color and if that works as well you can be sure that audio.play() is not working